# Saving particular format of data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am entering data in a field called description through a java application.Now my question is that the data that i am entering is aligned(i.e it consist of bullets and numbering and data,there are also spaces)is it possible to save data in mysql in the same format.Because when the same data(description data) is fetched through query the format changes to that of a paragraph which i dont want it to.Basically i want the data to be saved in the same format that it is in excel in mysql.Can this be possible.Can anyone one guide me for this.

From excel sheet one column will contain data in the following format.

TABLE OF CONTENTS

I. INTRODUCTION

Report Scope and Methodology
  Executive Summary

II. BUSINESS ENVIRONMENT

Economic Outlook
  Key Economic Indicators
  Industrial Output
  Population and Labor
  Foreign Investment
  Foreign Trade
  Financial and Tax Regulations
  Banking System and Regulations
  Foreign Exchange
  Taxes, Tariff and Custom Duties

III. METHIONINE INDUSTRY ASSESSMENTS

I want data to be saved in this same format so that while i am fetching it i get it in the format as above.

Answer (score 1):

try to use prepareStatement to execute query and set up values of fields inside that.

For Example,

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yeah, it would be saved and special characters and space would be handled as preparedStatement is pre-compiled.

Comment: if you got your solution then you can accept my answer as per stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: @ Jwalin Shah-Hey i apologise but its not working.Its still showing up in paragraph format.

Comment: post string value which you want to be displayed over here.

Comment: I have edited my question.Please let me know if its possible.

Comment: @ Jwalin Shah-Is It possible?